# Magnetar field energy density

Tags: astrophysics, magnetic-fields

According to Wikipedia a [Magnetar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetar)...

> Earth has a geomagnetic field of 30–60 microteslas, and a
>   neodymium-based, rare-earth magnet has a field of about 1 tesla, with
>   a magnetic energy density of 4.0×105 J/m3. A magnetar's 1010 tesla
>   field, by contrast, has an energy density of 4.0×1025 J/m3, with an
>   E/c2 mass density >104 times that of lead.

Is this correct? Does a 10^10 increase in field lead to a 10^20 increase in energy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the energy $u$ stored in a field $B$ in a region with permiability $\mu$ is given by:

$$u = \frac{1}{2}\frac{B^2}{\mu}$$

So if you double $B$ then $u$ gets quadrupled and if you increase $B$ by  a factor of $10^{10}$ then $u$ increases by $10^{2\times 10} = 10^{20}$.

I'm not quite sure about the assumptions that go into the above formula however (I'll see if I can find out) so it may or may not be valid for the extreme fields around a magnetar.

Comment: Simply heuristic: energy momentum of EM field is conserved if this is postulated as the energy density and Poynting vector as the energy flux (the two fulfil a [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem)).